# How to create a Scala Seq[String]() from within nashorn?

Tags: scala, nashorn

I need to create a Seq() object for feeding it into another Scala object from within nashorn. The class is imported into nashorn via

```
var seqClass = Java.type("scala.collection.Seq");
```

and the object creation looks like:

```
var seq = new seqClass();
```

But when creating the object for it, I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: Can not create new object with constructor scala.collection.Seq with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures. in <eval> at line number 13
```

I suspect the generic class for the Seq() is missing, but I cannot figure out how to add it to the above code.

Comment: Could you show the code you're using to create objects?

Comment: `scala.collection.Seq` is just a type alias. Could it be that you have to use `var seqClass = Java.type("scala.collection.immutable.Seq")`?

Comment: I just used var seq = new seqClass(); to create an object. Changing it to immutable Seq does not change the problem.

Comment: Aren't `Seq`s are abstract? Why do not you try to create `Vector`s or `::`s instead?

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks. However the object creation fails with the same TypeError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with Nashorn, but Scala `Seq`s and other collections are created by calling companion methods instead of constructors. Given my understanding, it should be something like

```
val seqCompanion = Java.type("scala.collection.immutable.Seq$").MODULE$
seqCompanion.empty()
```

EDIT: I expected `seqCompanion.apply(str1, str2, ...)` to work for non-empty sequences, but after checking it, the JVM signature of `Seq$.apply` is `public scala.collection.GenTraversable scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion.apply(scala.collection.Seq)` so it won't. You could do it by writing a Scala method which accepts an `Array[A]` and produces `Seq[A]` directly and calling it as above:

```
// scala
object SeqToArray { def a2s[A](a: Array[A]) = a.toSeq }

// Nashorn
Java.type("SeqToArray$").MODULE$.a2s([str1, ...])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The empty Seq() works like a charm. For the conversion function in Nashorn one needs to create a Java Array instead of a javascript array, following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492641/java8-js-nashorn-convert-array-to-java-array

Comment: @TeTeT Makes sense, I thought it would be converted automatically, but Nashorn doesn't really know the expected type here.